# Symfony does not detect relative url root

Tags: apache2, symfony-1.4

In symfony 1.4 in settings.yml we are using the option:

```
env:
  request:
    param: 
      relative_url_root: /name-of-app
```

to specify which relative_url_root an app uses. So every app runs under a different relative_url_root.

The problem is that symfony 1.4 routing does not detect this relative url root. So for example if we have the following route:

```
route_name:
  url:  /some-module/some-action
  param: { module: somemodule, action: someaction }
```

And we try to access `http://myproject.local/name-of-app/some-module/some-action` symfony tries to search for a route name which matches `name-of-app/some-module/some-action` instead of `/some-module/some-action`.

Also symfony now tries link to images using this relative_url_root, therefore images are not found anymore. Because images are only reachable via `http://project.local/img/..` instead of `http://project.local/name-of-app/img`

What is the best way to solve this?

1. Should I remove a '/' somewhere?
2. Should I use RewriteBase somehow in htaccess?
3. Should I strip 'name-of-app' in the REQUEST_URI using htaccess?
4. Prefix every routing url with name-of-app/?
5. Should I in someway tell apache that /name-of-app is some kind of path or prefix? Note that in our production environment we are not able to create virtual hosts so we have to solve this using .htaccess or symfony itself.
6. A very different solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fix for the routing:**

I changed my .htaccess as follows.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} myproject.local
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /name-of-app* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatcher.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

By using this rewrite rule symfony seems to recognize that /name-of-app is a prefix in the routing and somehow matches this on the `relative_url_root`. Now when I var_dump the sfRoute object in the controller I get the following.

```
object(sfRoute)[33]
  protected 'isBound' => boolean true
  protected 'context' => 
    array (size=7)
      'path_info' => string 'some-module/some-action' (length=10)
      'prefix' => string '/name-of-appp' (length=8)
      'method' => string 'GET' (length=3)
      'format' => null
      'host' => string 'myproject.local' (length=20)
      'is_secure' => boolean true
      'request_uri' => string 'https://myproject.local/name-of-app/some-module/some-action' (length=47)
```

Note that I did not change the routing rules as Michal suggested. Also I believe my approach with the `relative_url_root` is not really that strange as Symfony understands it.

**Fix for direct file access:**

In order to redirect a request like `https://myproject.local/name-of-app/some/path/to/a/file.ext` to `https://myproject.local/some/path/to/a/file.ext` I used  the following directives.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/name-of-app
RewriteRule ^name-of-app/(.*)$ https://myproject.local/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the `relative_url_root` is what you're really after. As [the documentation](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/05-Factories#chapter_05_sub_relative_url_root) states:

> relative_url_root
>
> The relative_url_root option defines the part of the URL before the front controller. Most of the time, this is automatically detected by the framework and does not need to be changed.

So it is part of the URL before `index.php` or `frontend_dev.php`, etc.

What you could do, in my opinion, is to write your own Routing class which will extend the `sfPatternRouting` and have it remove the prefix part of your URLs before trying to match any route. Then use this class for routing in `factories.yml`.

EDIT: I somehow missed the fact that you operate between different applications.

In general the `relative_url_root` is definitely not a good idea to separate calls to different apps. The best way, in my opinion, would be to use separate front controllers and Virtual Hosts to have different subdomains. Unfortunately you say you cannot go for this option.

You could then go for either of the solutions:

1. Fiddle with .htaccess and have it redirect your calls to a proper front controller: `myurl.com/path-to-app1/something` will call `app1.php/something` and `myurl.com/path-to-app2/something` will call `app2.php/something`.
2. Change the `index.php` file. Have it catch the first part of URL (`path-to-app/`) and based on it's value load the configuration for the proper app (e.g. `$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('app2', 'prod', false);`)
   You would then have to change your routes to take into consideration that there is this first part of URL (e.g. have all your routes start with a `:path-to-action` variable which will be passed to functions generating URLs), or use a parameter defined in config:

.

```
In apps/app1/config/app.yml
path_to_app: app1

In apps/app1/config/routing.yml
route1:
  url: <?php echo sfConfig::get('app_path_to_app') ?>/something
  ...
```

Comment: Yes but this would not solve the fact that my images are not found on the server. Also this will not work when using inter-app routing, that is, switching context and then generate an absolute url.

Comment: If you drop the `relative_root_url` setting and implement the routing class, the images will be found without problems.

Comment: Yes true, but then inter-app routing wont work. Note that when switching to another app and then generating an absolute url will incorporate this relative_root_url.

Comment: I didn't catch at first that you're using that to call different apps. See the edited answer above.

Comment: I changed my question; I also added a partial answer. Can you look at this?

Comment: I fixed it, see answer below.