# routing and module in symfony 1.4

Tags: .htaccess, symfony1, symfony-1.4, subdomain

I have a serious problem about routing and envirenement or module in symfony 1.4,so I created three modules frontend , mobile and backend.

So in frontend and mobile module,I'm using almost the same routing :

```
//apps/frontend/config/routing.yml

home:
 url:   /home
 param: { module: user, action: home }

homepage:
 url:   /
 param: { module: content, action: index } 

  ....

default_index:
 url:   /:module
 param: { action: index }

default:
 url:   /:module/:action/*
```

mobile module :

```
//apps/mobile/config/routing.yml

home:
 url:   /home
 param: { module: user, action: home }

homepage:
 url:   /
 param: { module: sfGuardAuth, action: signin } 

  ....

default_index:
 url:   /:module
 param: { action: index }

default:
 url:   /:module/:action/*
```

I use the link to access to my site

```
mysite.com/  ==> frontend module(frontend.php)
mysite.com/mobile.php ==> mobile module(mobile.php)
```

The problem is when I access to mobile version to login page correctly but after login they redirect me to homepage of frontend module not to the home page of mobile module?

Remark :

when I use this link `mysite.com/mobile_dev.php` with dev env the mobile version works very fine!

Edit :

here is my htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(%2d|-)[^=]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1? [L]
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
 # getting no_script_name to work
 RewriteBase /

# we skip all files with .something
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
#RewriteRule .* - [L]

# we check if the .html version is here (caching)
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# no, so we redirect to our front web controller
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

So when I change `index.php` to `mobile.php` the link `mysite.com/mobile.php`go directly to to mobile version homepage and all works fine...

So my issue now is how to edit my .htaccess to redirect me like this :

```
mysite.com/index.php or mysite.com/  redirect me to my site 
mysite.com/mobile.php redirect me to mobile version
```

Edit2 :

I explain you,when I start with this link `mysite.com/mobile.php` so it redirect me to mobile apps to login page but when after login instead it go to my homepage the new request search  default front controller  and it point on index.php so that give me the homepage of frontend apps not the mobile apps!

So why symfony with `mobile_dev.php` keep in memory it all time that we are in mobile dev env and with `mobile.php`it switch me from prod mobile env to frontend prod env in first redirection?

Comment: You should check if there is only one [`no_script_name: true`](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/04-Settings#chapter_04_sub_no_script_name) in all `settings.yml`.

Comment: yes in frontend and mobile they are no_script_name: true in all settings.yml in them both,that mean?

Comment: That means incorrect configuration... you should read the linked documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sfGaurdModule redirects to route `homepage` after successful login. Your `homepage` route in both apps have a URL defined as `/`. So when you login to `frontend` or `mobile` you are redirected to `http://mysite.com/`.

As one URL can only describe one resource there is no way your web server can understand which application you want to use when it gets the URL `http://mysite.com/`. It looks into .htaccess and sees that it should treat this URL as referring to `http://mysite.com/index.php` (frontend application). That's why you get redirected to frontend all the time.

There is nothing you can do with .htaccess to change it as you will never be able to differentiate just the URL `http://mysite.com/`.

What you can do is:

- either  change the URL of the homepage for mobile app to e.g. `/mobile_home` and switch `no_script_name` to `false` for the mobile app
- or overwrite the `signin()` function of the `sfGuardAuth` module so it will redirect to different pages based on the application you now use.

Either way remember to set `no_script_name` to `false` in one of your apps as it will always cause a problem if you don't do this.

As for the `dev` environment. It works because after login in dev you are never redirected to `/` but either to `frontend_dev.php` or `mobile_dev.php` so the server does not get confused.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, you cannot use 2 times `no_script_name: true` (for your frontend and mobile apps), only once if it's on the same domain/subdomain!

Comment: Ok I remove no_script_name: true from mobile and I keep it in frontend,it's dosn't work I have the same problem...

Comment: the solution is not there,it must use htaccess to redirect us everytime we call `mobile.php`....

Comment: So I don't see what the problem is. But I don't think you need to edit the .htaccess file to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into `relative_url_root`, I also had an issue with this: [Symfony does not detect relative url root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982583/symfony-does-not-detect-relative-url-root/15039204#15039204).

Comment: I don't get your solution,I add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mobile/?
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mobile.php [QSA,L]` in my htaccess and it's work on local server only but on line it's not...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **sfGuardPlugin** or **sfDoctrineGuardPlugin** you have to check the plugin code to modify the redirect behavior. sf 1.4 have poor multiple app support. And just to clarify you have created three "**apps**" not three "modules", as you said.